# Allow delphi to use 0x56 in a variable. I can't seem to find anything on the internet other than converting Hex into something else

Tags: delphi, hex

I need to be able to put 0x56 into a variable, but for some reason I can only find things on converting Hex into integers etc.

Comment: Data types are not hexadecimal they store just numbers. For printing numbers usually uses the decimal format but in code you directly assign hexadecimal values by using e.g. $56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hex notation is just a way to represent a number. See [Numerals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi)#Numerals).
In Delphi you can assign hex values to a number by using the `$` prefix.
A text string can also be converted to a number using a `0x` prefix. [SysUtils.StrToInt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt)

Se the example program below to get a grip of it:

```
program Project174;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  X: Integer;
begin
  x := $56;               // Hex notation (base 16)
  WriteLn(x);             // Writes 86
  x := StrToInt('0x56');
  WriteLn(x);             // Writes 86
  x := StrToInt('$56');
  WriteLn(x);             // Writes 86
  X := 86;                // Decimal notation (base 10)
  WriteLn(X);             // Writes 86
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: If he want character ‘56’ or ‘0x56’ then you can prefix the ‘number’ with a #. Ex `#56` or `#$56`